# How i can use a project from github in my existing project in nextjs?

Tags: github, next.js13

**I am using Nextjs 14 app directory project.**

I want to use lexical-playground https://github.com/facebook/lexical/tree/main/packages/lexical-playground in my project.

This is not available via npm, i have following issues -

1. How to deal with `package.json`, because my project already have `package.json`. Should i merge it?
2. What about **imports** in lexical project, because if i place it within my project somewhere it may break imports.
3. Is there any better way to acheive what i want to do?